# Having trouble connecting to LinkedIn API with rauth

Tags: python, oauth, linkedin-api, rauth

I'm trying to run the example code from `rauth`'s repo on github https://github.com/litl/rauth/blob/master/examples/linkedin-updates.py to connect to the LinkedIn API but I keep getting HTTP 400 errors.

The specific line in question is `linkedin.get_request_token()`.

The example uses `HTTP GET` but the LinkedIn documentation uses `HTTP POST`.

If anyone can help me use `rauth` or `requests` to connect to LinkedIn, that would be awesome

Answer (score 0):

Could you take a look at the revised example and see if that works for you? Here's [a link](https://github.com/litl/rauth/blob/c6447ddb5427246d58e6c2077bdc71404b4d1def/examples/linkedin-updates-cli.py) for you. Please note that this will require updating rauth to 0.5.x and updating Requests to 1.1.0.

This example seems to be functional from here. Let me know if you run into any additional complications. Also always feel free to open issues on GitHub directly. We try to respond as quickly as we can.